# How to redirect after login

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to redirect a user to different page after user is authenticated. I am using jwt authentication and I tried with `$location`, `$window` for redirection but its throwing error `$state.go is not a function`. I am new to angular and I am guessing there should be way to redirect may using a service in angular but I am still new to factories and service.

I have my state provider like this in `state.js` file:

```
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // default route
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/Home");
    var header = {
        templateUrl: 'commonViews/Header.html',
        controller: function ($scope) {
        }

    };
    var footer = {
        templateUrl: 'commonViews/Footer.html',
        controller: function ($scope) {
        }
    };
    // ui router states
$stateProvider
    .state('Home', {
        url: "/Home",
        views: {
            header: header,
            content: {
                templateUrl: 'views/HomePage.html',
                controller: function ($scope) {
                }
            },
            footer: footer
        }
    })
    .state('LoggedIn', {
        url: "/LoggedIn",
        views: {
            'header': header,
            'content': {
                templateUrl: 'views/LoggedIn.html',
                controller: function () {
                }
            },
            'footer': footer
        }
    });
});
```

and `loginController.js`:

```
myApp.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http', 'jwtHelper', '$localStorage', '$state', function ($scope, $http, jwtHelper, $localStorage, $sessionStorage, $state)
{
$scope.email = "";
$scope.password = "";
$scope.token = "";

$scope.loginForm = function () {

    var data = {email: $scope.email, password: $scope.password};
    var url = 'rs/loginResource/login';
    $http.post(url, data).then(function (response)
    {
        $localStorage.token = response.data.token;
        console.log("Encoded Token in localstorage is:" + $localStorage.token);

        if ($localStorage.token) {
         // $location.url("/LoggedIn");
            $state.go('/LoggedIn');
        }

    }, function (error)
    {
        console.log("error", error);
    });
};
}]);
```

further I have to perform refresh token based on expiration time etc, so is it better to have separate the functions like using a service to do the signup and signin?

Comment: remove the forward slash `/`, it should be `$state.go('LoggedIn')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the definition of your controller and the way you're handling your injections. And no, referring to your own answer to your question, the problem is not the "order" of the injections. It's a bit worse.

```
myApp.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http', 'jwtHelper', '$localStorage', '$state', function ($scope, $http, jwtHelper, $localStorage, $sessionStorage, $state)
```

in this code you're mapping `'$scope'` to a `$scope` variable, `'$http'` to `$http`, `'jwtHelper'` to `jwtHelper`, `'$localStorage'` to `$localStorage` and `'$state'` to `$sessionStorage`, and you're not mapping anything to `$state`. So obviously you get an error when you try to call a method on an undefined `$state` variable.
So in short, you're injecting 5 dependencies and you're assigning 6 variables to your dependencies, which in turn results in things not doing what they're supposed to do.

Comment: hmm Actually you are right I re-changed the code as it was in question and added `$sessionStorage` to map accordingly and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular $window:

```
$window.location.href = '/index.html';
```

Comment: Its throwing error: `Error: $window is not defined`

Comment: $window needs to be injected.

For example:

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope, $window) {

Comment: also you can use $location.path('/newValue');

Answer (score 0):

`$state. go` accepts the view *name*, not the *URL*. Replace `'/LoggedIn'` with `Logged` and you should be good.

Comment: I get `$state is undefined` error even after injecting in controller function

Answer (score 0):

You need to add $window as a dependency to your controller if you are using $window,

```
myApp.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http', 'jwtHelper', '$localStorage', '$state','$window', function ($scope, $http, jwtHelper, $localStorage, $sessionStorage, $state,$window)
{
$window.location.href = '/index.html';
}
```

otherwise change the route like this, here also you need to inject $state,

```
  myApp.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http', 'jwtHelper', '$localStorage', '$state','$window','$state', function ($scope, $http, jwtHelper, $localStorage, $sessionStorage, $state,$window,$state)
{
      $state.go('LoggedIn');
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same error: `$window is undefined`

Comment: I injected `$window` and tried it but still the same error

Comment: add the $state as a dependency to your controller

Comment: tried with both `$state` and `$window`. Both injections throwing error undefined

Comment: can you post your module declaration?

Comment: `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router','angular-jwt','ngStorage']);`

Comment: I redeployed my app and now it is throwing different error: `Error: $state.go is not a function`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99511/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-satyadev).

Comment: How do I define states properly?

Answer (score 0):

Use $state.go instead of `$window` and `location`.
Add $state injector on controller
write code `$state.go('LoggedIn');`
Instead `$state.go('/LoggedIn');`

> Write state name('LoggedIn') instead of url('/LoggedIn').

Hopefully this will work in your case.